# How to load Different Collection view cell styles within one Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

Actually i want to achieve the below design [image: Entire tableview design]

Here I’m using XIB for loading different collectionviews in each section of tableview. This is my design structure of Viewcontroller and collectionview cell within tableview cell.
[image: XIB design structure] [image]

I have tried something, that's for your reference.

**Tableviewcell.m**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
    [collection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ScheduleCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellid"];
    [collection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ResultCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellno"];
    [collection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ResultCell1" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellno1"];
    [collection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ResultCell2" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellno2"];
    [collection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ResultCell3" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellno3"];



}

-(void)configureCell:(id <UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>)delegate andIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath andTitile:(NSString *)title{
    collection.dataSource = delegate;
    collection.delegate = delegate;
    collection.tag = indexPath.section;

    NSLog(@"collectionArray %ld",(long)collection.tag);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.collection reloadData];
    });


}
```

**Viewcontroller.m**

I called that configure cell method from below delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[Tablecell configureCell:self andIndex:indexPath andTitile:@"Events"];

}
```

All are called but i could not get collectionview.tag from their corresponding delegate.So, i could not load different collectionview cells here. Any one direct me to right way if i'm wrong.

**Your suggestions are welcome in swift or Objective-c**

i have problem with loading different cells.Here that collectionView.tag always nil.When assigning tag in `configurecell` method its not assigning. Because that `collection` memory is not allocated .I could not load different cells.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell* ColCell;

    if (collectionView.tag == 1) {

        ScheduleCell* cell = (ScheduleCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellid" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.eventNamelbl.text = @"ScheduleCell";
        ColCell = cell;
    }
    else if (collectionView.tag == 2){

        ResultCell* cell = (ResultCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellno" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.resultlbl.text = @"ResultCell";
        ColCell = cell;

    }
    else if (collectionView.tag == 3){

        ResultCell1* cell = (ResultCell1 *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellno1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.resultlbl.text = @"ResultCell";
        ColCell = cell;
    }
    else if (collectionView.tag == 4){

        ResultCell2* cell = (ResultCell2 *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellno2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.resultlbl.text = @"ResultCell";
        ColCell = cell;

    }
    else if (collectionView.tag == 5){

        ResultCell3* cell = (ResultCell3 *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellno3" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.resultlbl.text = @"ResultCell";
        ColCell = cell;

    }


    return  ColCell;
}
```

Comment: Define your CollectionView delegates inside the TableCell and format your data the way you want to show, and pass the data to each TableCell to display CollectionView Cell, to capture action out you can use Protocols.

Comment: where is your tableview code

Comment: Don't call `[Tablecell configureCell:self andIndex:indexPath andTitile:@"Events"];` in `willDisplay`, call it in `cellForRow` delegate method.